# ServiceStack Enum Serilization vs WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, servicestack

I'm moving a service from WebApi to Service Stack and it seems that webapi turned my enums to ints, but SS is returning the actual enum string.  Now globally changing things to do one or the other is not an option as it'll bork the CMS, but can I not tell a single method to just return the int value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell ServiceStack to serialize Enums as integers globally with:

```
JsConfig.TreatEnumAsInteger = true;
```

Or an a adhoc basis by annotating using enums with a `[Flags]` attribute, e.g:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum { ... }
```